# Bitbucket web hook not posting

Tags: push, bitbucket, webhooks

I have set up a web hook on Bitbucket to POST to my webserver to log some details. There is two webhooks on the repo, my custom one, and one for FTPloy.com. I have been pushing random commits to test the POST on my server etc, but after a while it stopped.

Never FTPloy.com or my own webserver receives a post request from Bitbucket after I pushed.

How is this possible/how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a hard time testing my web hook as well. I figured out that the best way to test is via command line. I copied the sample data shown [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+Service+Management), added `payload=` to the beginning and saved it to a file: `bb.post`

Then via command line I submitted a POST request to my web hook using that file as the POST data: `curl --data @bb.post http://mydomain.com/customWebHook.php`

This is the best way I found to debug it.

> Note: They never mention that when the last commit was from a merge, the "branch" attribute from that commit is null. Instead you need to look at "branches" attribute which is an array of the two branches that created the merge.